# SQL Server TimeSeries optimization with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, time-series

Currently, I'm looking for the optimal way to store data points in a SQL server table, and then read large quantities of them within a .NET APP (Target framework: 3.1). Right now I'm storing my data in a table structure like

```sql
CREATE TABLE [DataPoints](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](19, 9) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Index] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [DateTime] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**Id**: is TimeSeries id.
**DateTime**:  value timestamp.
**Value**:  TimeSeries value.

Now, my main issue is the reading part (storage is done over night so consistent write speeds are not important), I'm currently doing some stress tests that includes reading from this table 5 years worth of data for at least 500 TimeSeries ids and this rounds up to `160.000.000` records. Querying this amount of records takes on average **7:30** minutes, more or less.

I'm using Entity framework to retrieve the data, and I've tried different approaches:

1. Going one TimeSeries id at a time (ranges between **7:20-7:40** minutes)

```cs
var dataPoints = context.DataPoints
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .Where(dataPoint => dataPoint.id == id &&
                                            dataPoint.DateTimeUtc >= startDate &&
                                            dataPoint.DateTimeUtc <= endDate);
```

2. Including all ids in the query (ranges between **7:30-8:10** minutes)

```cs
List<int> ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4, .... 498, 499, 500 };
var dataPoints = context.DataPoints
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .AsQueryable()
                        .Where(dataPoint => ids.Contains(dataPoint.Id) &&
                                            dataPoint.DateTimeUtc >= startDate &&
                                            dataPoint.DateTimeUtc <= endDate);
```

Basically I just want to know if there is a better way to read this amount of data using SQL server and improve the times it takes to query.

I've also read about `InfluxDB`, `Timescale` and `MongoDB` but before moving to those technologies, I wanted to know if what I want if feasible using the current SQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

That's really not an optimal table design for reading.  There's not even an efficient way to seek to a particular Id, so you'll have to scan through all the IDs for the date range.

Try a partitioned columnstore.  Columnstores have the best compression and scan speed, and each 1M row chunk has min/max values for each column so can be efficiently skipped.  Then partitioning breaks up the table by putting different IDs in different physical data structures.

```
create partition function pf_tsid(int) as range right for values (0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700)
create partition scheme ps_tsid as partition pf_tsid all to ([Primary])


CREATE TABLE [DataPoints](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [decimal](19, 9) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Index] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [DateTime] ASC,
        [Id] ASC
    ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
) on ps_tsid(Id)

create clustered columnstore index cci_DataPoints on DataPoints
```

You can go as far as to put each time series in its own partition if you like.

Comment: Thanks David, I'm going to give it a try and let you know how it goes, its taking some time to store all those data points into this new table.

Comment: Hey David, a few questions, is it normal that the storage process takes too long? previously in my experiments, storing 160 million records took about two hours (bulk insert), now with this table structure you proposed it takes too long. Does the columnstore index makes the OLTP's operations cost more? and, when it comes to querying the data, will date filters affect the performance of the query? should I only query by ids?

Comment: Yes.  Columnstore does more work in data loading to compress the data and prepare it for fast scanning.  Data loading guidance is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-loading-guidance?view=sql-server-ver16  And you should filter by whatever makes sense.  A combination of dates and IDs should work well.